# What’s the meaning of this square with a down arrow icon on my HomePod in Control Center?

Tags: ios, homepod, dashboard

This is first time I see this icon.

[image]

What’s it’s meaning?

It’s in Control Center. The HomePods are in “Salon”.

[image]

I’m wondering about the icon on the right:

[image]

Comment: Do you own a Homepod?

Comment: Yes 2 paired home pods

Comment: What’s the context of that icon?  Control Center or something else?  Can you expand the screen shot? Did you name the HomePod(s) “Salon?”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A software update is available for HomePod

> 2. Open the Home app.
> 3. Tap or click the More button [image], then Home Settings [image] > Software Update.

[Update HomePod - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208247)